# Use Sequelize to get Json from value

Tags: sequelize.js

I have to get value from 1 col which currently stores a JSON as TEXT:

> col1: {"class":{"count":3,"number":25}}

So when I use sequlize orm with option:

```
..attributes: ['id', 'col1']..
```

it returns value in:

```
"{\"class\":{\"count\":3,\"number\":25}}"
```

How can I use something like:

```
..attributes: ['id', sequelize.json('col1')]..
```

to get data in JSON format?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `sequelize.json`...

You could use JSON.parse and a getter on the column.

```
 sequelize.define('your_table', {
   col1: {
     type: DataTypes.TEXT,
     get(val) { return JSON.parse(val) }
   }
 })
```

But Postgres (and I think MySQL, although I don't see it in the sequelize docs) have JSON field types. They'll be much better. You can query by both keys and values at arbitrary nesting. You can also create indexes. Again, they may only be possible with Postgres.

```
 sequelize.define('your_table', {
   col1: {
     type: DataTypes.JSONB,
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set `{raw: true}` when you are making a find query in database. This will return json object

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and here is my solution:

```
sequelize.define("your_table", {

col1: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,      
      get: function () {
                 return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue("col1"));
             } 
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how if set all my Sequelize JSON type columns. This prevent error from reading the DataBase especially in MariaDB where JSON are LONGTEXT more than in MYSQL where there is a special JSON type.

```
MyGreatJSONColumnName: {
    type : DataTypes.JSON,
    defaultValue : [],
    get(){
        let tab =   this.getDataValue("MyGreatJSONColumnName");
        if(typeof tab === 'string' || tab instanceof String) try{tab = JSON.parse(tab);}catch(e){tab=undefined};
        if(!tab) return [];
        else return tab;
    }
}
```

or if you wand an object like column

```
MyGreatJSONColumnName: {
    type : DataTypes.JSON,
    defaultValue : {},
    get(){
        let tab =   this.getDataValue("MyGreatJSONColumnName");
        if(typeof tab === 'string' || tab instanceof String) try{tab = JSON.parse(tab);}catch(e){tab=undefined};
        if(!tab) return {};
        else return tab;
    }
}
```